# MPV seems to change dpms setting

Tags: debian, screensaver, dpms, mpv

***Context***

I am runnning a Debian Stretch distribution with Cinnamon graphical interface.

I use this command to turn off the display

```
 xset dpms force off
```

It is useful to me when I want to sleep and just launch a video without being perturbed by the light of my screen.
Note that if the mouse pointer is active (moves), then the display is turn on.

***Problem***

If the video is launched by VLC or Totem Movie Player, all is working fine.

If the video is launched by mplayer, I have to add the line

```
[default]
stop-xscreensaver=0
```

to my configuration file ~.mplayer/mplayer.conf and it's fine.

But I would like to use the mpv player and I don't know how to configure it so that mpv doesn't change dpms setting.

It is related to the question :
[Debian DPMS - Mplayer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404941/debian-dpms-mplayer)
which solves the problem with mplayer.